# Chat over network in linux 5.5 version?

Tags: networking

Is there any way to chat over network in Linux 5.5 version like gnome meeting in Linux 3.5? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Wnat is linux 5.5?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iptux](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/iptux/)

iptux is an IP Messenger client for Linux.

It supports:

```
auto detect other clients in the intranet.
send message to other clients.
send file to other clients.
```